# Modifying cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have `neo4j` data as like as given below:

[image]

Here I have `COUNTEY_PROVINCE` relationship between `country` and `province`, `PROVINCE_CITY` relationship between `province` and `city` and `COUNTRY_CITY` relationship between `country` and `city`. When user call an api with `country name`, I want to return all `province` with `city`. To do this, I have run the following query:

```
 MATCH path=(cn:Country { name: "Bangladesh" })-[:COUNTRY_PROVINCE]->(pv:Province)-[:PROVINCE_CITY]->(ct:City)
 RETURN { x:  nodes(path)  }
```

And I have got the following result **( country, province, city )** :

```
  { x: nodes(path) }
  { "x": [ { "name": "Bangladesh"}, { "name": "Dhaka" }, { "name": "Dhaka" } ] }
  { "x": [ { "name": "Bangladesh"}, { "name": "Dhaka" }, { "name": "Narayanganj" } ] }
  { "x": [ { "name": "Bangladesh"}, { "name": "Sylhet" }, { "name": "Sylhet" } ] }
  { "x": [ { "name": "Bangladesh"}, { "name": "Khulna" }, { "name": "Khulna" }  ] }
  { "x": [ { "name": "Bangladesh"}, { "name": "Khulna" }, { "name": "Jessore" }  ]  }
  { "x": [ { "name": "Bangladesh"}, { "name": "Chittagong" }, { "name": "Chittagong" }  ]  }
  { "x": [ { "name": "Bangladesh"}, { "name": "Chittagong" }, { "name": "Comilla" }  ]  }
```

Now my question is, how can I get country list with province and associate cities like :

```
 [
    {
       country: {
           name: "Bangladesh",
           province: [
              {
                  name: "Dhaka",
                  city: [
                      { name: "Dhaka" },
                      { name: "Narayanganj" }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  name: "Sylhet",
                  city: [
                      { name: "Sylhet" }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  name: "Chittagong",
                  city: [
                      { name: "Chittagong" },
                      { name: "Comilla" }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  name: "Khulna",
                  city: [
                      { name: "Khulna" },
                      { name: "Jessore" }
                  ]
              }            
           ]
       }
    }
 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simulated your scenario here.

Load the initial data set (Similar to the data set described in the question):

```
CREATE (c:Country {name:"Country A"})
CREATE (p1:Province {name:"Province A"})
CREATE (p2:Province {name:"Province B"})
CREATE (c1:City {name:"City A"})
CREATE (c2:City {name:"City B"})
CREATE (c3:City {name:"City C"})
CREATE (c4:City {name:"City D"})
CREATE (c)-[:COUNTRY_PROVINCE]->(p1)
CREATE (p1)-[:PROVINCE_CITY]->(c1)
CREATE (p1)-[:PROVINCE_CITY]->(c2)
CREATE (c)-[:COUNTRY_PROVINCE]->(p2)
CREATE (p2)-[:PROVINCE_CITY]->(c3)
CREATE (p2)-[:PROVINCE_CITY]->(c4)
```

The query:

```
MATCH (cn:Country { name: "Country A" })-[:COUNTRY_PROVINCE]->(pv:Province)-[:PROVINCE_CITY]->(ct:City)
WITH cn, pv, collect({name : ct.name}) as cities
RETURN {coutry : {name : cn.name, province : collect( distinct { name:pv.name, city :cities }) } }
```

The result:

```
{
   "coutry":{
      "name":"Country A",
      "province":[
         {
            "name":"Province A",
            "city":[
               {
                  "name":"City B"
               },
               {
                  "name":"City A"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"Province B",
            "city":[
               {
                  "name":"City D"
               },
               {
                  "name":"City C"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

The above query uses the [collect()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) function and the [DISTINCT](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/operators/#syntax-using-the-distinct-operator) operator to achieve the desired format.

Comment: Here's a minor variation on Bruno's answer using map projection from Neo4j 3.1.x: `MATCH (country:Country { name: "Country A" })-[:COUNTRY_PROVINCE]->(province:Province)-[:PROVINCE_CITY]->(city:City)
WITH country, province {.name, city:collect(city {.name})} as province
RETURN [country {.name, province:collect(province)}] as country`

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're going to return the nodes of a path, that's obviously what you are going to get. You've got several options to do it differently :

1. Check out https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index32.html#_from_tojson, for example **apoc.convert.toTree** may get you very close to what you want.
2. Do it yourself. Send the query from any client application and process (+ format) the results yourself (in Java, Python, C#, ...)
3. ...

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'm looking `apoc.convert.toTree` I already get this result using javascript `reduce` and looking for `neo4j` solution.